# Button looks bad on line break

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small problem. When my button doesn't fit table cell, line gets broken. But button in new line looks bad ("sticked" to button above, as in picture). How to make it at least have some neat top margin, to "unstick" it from the top button?!

Here's an example:

[image: example]

And here is the code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Szczegóły</a>                        
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Uprawnienia</a>                     
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edytuj</a>                    
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Usuń</a> <!-- this button looks bad -->
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.btn{
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: 10px is too far, but 5px is fine. I know the CSS, and yet I haven't thought of that simple solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use table-cell? I would recommend display: inline-block;

```
.container {
  margin-left: -20px;  
}
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Uhm, because it's in actual table? You misunderstood: I talk about <table> cell, not display: table-cell

Comment: Then you should refactor it without table ;)

Comment: I don't think so, because it's in table, that is used properly (for dispalying data, buttons are just "actions" for record).

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding this CSS?

```
.fa {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: .fa is actually icon class, not button class.